# Grunt uglify doesn't work on multiple files

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, uglifyjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I am trying to uglify multiple .js files in a directory using `grunt-contrib-uglify`. My root directory looks like this:

```
--src
   example-project.js
   style.scss
--build
Gruntfile.js
package.JSON
```

and my Gruntfile.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    uglify: {
      build: {
        files: [{
          exapand : true,
          cwd: 'src',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: 'build',
          ext: '.min.js'        
        }]
      }
    },
    sass:{
      dist: {
        files: {
          'build/style.css' : 'src/style.scss'
        }
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'sass']);

};
```

When I try to run `grunt` on the root directory, I get this output:

```
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
>> Source file example-project.js not found.
>> Destination build not written because src files were empty.
>> No files created.
```

The sass part works fine.

I have checked [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839766/grunt-uglify-not-finding-files) and still it won't work.

Comment: EDIT: 
I mistyped the filesystem structure, the .js files are under the 'src' folder (where they should be)

Comment: You have a typo in your grunt file, may or may not be the cause of it: `exapand` -> `expand`

Comment: James Thorpe thanks for your help. I totally missed that. It works!