# grunt uglify does not find or compress files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm totally new to Grunt and am trying to minify javascript files using [uglify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify).
But no output files are generated, I'm not sure if the files are found or if it's just not creating the desired output.

The folder structure I have is:

```
--my1stgrunt  
  -js
    -min  
    -src
     companysearch.js
     excanvas.js  

  -node_modules  
  Gruntfile.js  
  package.json
```

When running `grunt` from root `my1stgrunt` I get:

> Running "default" task
>   Hello, from the default grunt task!
>   Done, without errors.

I already checked here:
[Grunt uglify not finding files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839766/grunt-uglify-not-finding-files)

**grunt.js**

```
module.exports = function(grunt){ // 1

grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
      files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'js/src',
          src: 'js/src/*.js',
          dest: 'js/min/',
          ext : '.min.js',
      }]
    }
  }
});

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); //https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify


  grunt.registerTask('default', function() { // 4
      grunt.log.writeln('Hello, from the default grunt task!'); // 5
  });

}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here's my folder structure, so there's no miscommunication as to what it looks like (grunt file is in root my1stgrunt):

[image]

```
module.exports = function(grunt){ // 1

grunt.initConfig({
  uglify: {
    my_target: {
      files: [{
          expand: true,
          src: '**/*.js',
          dest: 'js/min/',
          ext : '.min.js',
      }]
    }
  }
});



  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); //https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-uglify


  grunt.registerTask('default', function() { // 4
      grunt.log.writeln('Hello, from the default grunt task!'); // 5
  });

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your file structure, it looks a little ambiguous. shouldn't your source be `src: 'js/*.js',`, since it appears that your `companysearch.js` and `excanvas.js` are not in the `src` folder?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII thanks for pointing that out. I updated the file structure, the js files are in the src folder actually. I also updated the `src` attribute value...still nothing is written in the output folder though...

Comment: grasping at straws, but you might try `src: '**/*.js'`

Comment: Commenting out `cwd` should do the trick.

Comment: Have you tried using ``grunt uglify`` instead of using ``grunt`` cause using only ``grunt`` command  will trigger the default task, and in your case you are not calling the uglify task.

Comment: @hamism Ah, thanks! That creates new folders `\min\js\src` and in that last folder the 2 minified files are created. I had to change `src` back to `src: 'js/src/*.js'` otherwise some sort of loop occurred. How now would I be able to create the output directly in the root of `\min` instead of the `\js\src` sbufolder? Also, is it possible to set the `src` to a folder outside the grunt project folder? Thanks!